# override default angularjs error messages - "Required" "Invalid"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input field, where i have to show `error messages`, but its not working.. the `error messages` are not shown.

```
     <div class="form-group grouped">
        <div>
          <label for="card-routingNumber">Number:</label>
          <input name="cr" ng-model="card.rn" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="card-rn" class="form-control" validate-on="submit" required />
           <span class="help-block" ng-show"form.cr.$error.required">Field is empty</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When i click on submit, i need to show an error message if the input is empty.. but when i try... it always says `"Required"`

Answer (score 0):

Add "novalidate" attribute to your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show=**"!myForm.myInput.$valid"**>Field is empty</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **required** attribute from the `<input>`

```
<input name="cr" ng-model="card.rn" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="card-rn" class="form-control" validate-on="submit" />
```